# Why does Sequelize pluralize 'media' to medium

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm having a really big issue with sequelize trying to give me its best guess at what it thinks my table name is.

I have 3 tables. Properties, Media and a junction table PropertyMedia

For some reason when I do a join query with sequelize it gives me the error

`error: column Properties->PropertyMedia.medium_id does not exist`

I have done a global search to make sure that I don't have the word medium anywhere and I don't

```
let Media = sequelize.define('Media', {
    url: DataTypes.STRING,
    isVideo: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
}, { freezeTableName: true, tableName: 'media' });

let PropertyMedia = sequelize.define('PropertyMedia', {
    propertyId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    mediaId: DataTypes.INTEGER
}, { freezeTableName: true, tableName: 'property_media' });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't *pluralize* to "medium", it *singularizes* to "medium".

That is because ["media" is the plural of "medium"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/media#Noun_2) and by default table names use the plural and references use the singular, just like you'd have `user_id` (singular) reference `users` (plural), so here `medium_id` (not `media_id`) is expected to reference `media`.

It's true that nowadays in English [another (usually) uncountable noun "media"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/media#Noun_3) emerged from that (probably<sup>1</sup> from people forgetting that it does originate from the Latin word medium in plural), but that's a special case Sequelize doesn't know about, really, and also it couldn't discern which of the two nouns you meant.

For this reason, Sequelize has [ways to override the singular/plural forms](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/naming-strategies.html#overriding-singulars-and-plurals-when-defining-aliases).

---

<sub>**1**: I'm not an etymologist so please take this with a grain of salt.</sub>